# How to set SDK directory in gradle project

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, build.gradle

I want to set the default SDK for all projects because when I open a gradle project this error appears:

> The SDK directory 'D:\androidproject\com.guvery.notifyme_15_src\com.guvery.notifyme_15_src.tar.gz\home\vagrant\android-sdk' does not exist. Please fix the 'sdk.dir' property in the local.properties file.

[image: image with the error]

How can I fix it?

Comment: Rewrote part of the question/title to make the problem easier to understand. Also added the linked image.

Answer (score 2):

In a single project, open the `local.properties` file and set the

```
sdk.dir=/home/myFolder/androidSdk
```

To change the sdk dir for all project, in Android Studio.
**File -> Other Setting -> Default project structure**

[image]

Comment: running the build will overtire that value, this doesn't work.